# Why can I not find kernel-image

Tags: debian, apt

I'm attempting to remotly install Debian Etch on a CentOS system using the tutorial [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-remotely-install-debian-over-a-rh-based-distro-p2), when I get to the steps:

```
apt-cache search kernel-image
...
apt-get -y install kernel-image-2.6-686
```

apt is unable to find the kernel-image package in the repos.  I'm finding it hard to believe that it's gone,am I doing something wrong, has the package been renamed, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Just a point, why are you using etch? It's archived, old, unsupported and unmaintained. Squeeze is getting really close now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be named `linux-image-{version}-{arch}`, i.e.:  `linux-image-2.6-686`.